# Regular Expression - Small change needed

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need a regular expression that will allow only a to z and 0 to 9. I came across the function below on this site, but it allows a few symbols thru (#.-). How should it be done if it has to allow only a to z (both upper and lower case) and 0 to 9? I'm scared to edit it since I know nothing about regular expressions.

Also is this regular expression good to check for a to z and 0 to 9, or is there any way it can be bettered.

```
function isValid($str) {
    return !preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9.#\\-$]/', $str);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Is this PHP? Always specify flavor when asking regex question to get the most helpful answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seems to be what you need in this case:

```
function isValid($str) {
    return !preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', $str);
}
```

The `[…]` regex construct is called a *character class*. Something like `[aeiou]` matches one of any of the vowels.

The `[^…]` is a *negated* character class, so `[^aeiou]` matches one of *anything but* the vowels (which includes consonants, digits, symbols, etc).

The `-`, depending on where/how it appears in a character class definition, is a *range definition*, so `0-9` is the same as `0123456789`.

Thus, the regex `[^A-Za-z0-9]` actually matches a character that's neither a letter nor a digit. This is why the result of `preg_match` is negated with `!`.

That is, the logic of the above method uses *double negation*:

```
isValid = it's not the case that
              there's something other than a letter or a digit
                  anywhere in the string
```

You can alternatively get rid of the double negation and use something like this:

```
function isValid($str) {
    return preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9]*$/', $str);
}
```

Now there's no negation. The `^` and `$` are the beginning and of the string anchors, and `*` is a zero-or-one-of repetition metacharacter. Now the logic is simply:

```
isValid = the entire string from beginning to end
              is a sequence of letters and digits
```

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), [Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), [Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

#### Related questions

- [Regex: why doesn’t [01-12] range work as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148240/regex-why-doesnt-01-12-range-work-as-expected/)

  - Detailed discussion, with common mistakes, etc
- [Character class subtraction, converting from Java syntax to RegexBuddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201689/character-class-subtraction-converting-from-java-syntax-to-regexbuddy/)

  - Some flavors have rich character class arithmetics like subtraction and intersection

---

#### Non-regex alternative

Some languages have standard functions/idiomatic ways to validate that a string consists of only alphanumeric characters (among other possible string "types").

In PHP, for example, you can use [`ctype_alnum`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php).

> `bool ctype_alnum  (  string $text  )`
>
> Checks if all of the characters in the provided string , `text`, are alphanumeric.

#### API links

- [PHP Ctype Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ctype.php) - list of entire family of `ctype` functions

  - `ctype_alpha`, `digit`, `lower`, `upper`, `space`, etc

Comment: Thanks for the correction and also for pointing me to ctype_alnum. I never knew php had a function like that. I think i'll use that from now on.

Comment: +1 You are an expert at regex, would you please check the regex here in my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381331/jquery-convert-br-and-br-and-p-and-such-to-new-line/3381470#3381470

Answer (score 2):

Whilst I have nothing against regular expressions, with such a simple pattern you should probably consider using

```
if(ctype_alnum($input)) {
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php

Comment: Just discovered this function here :-) It makes things real easy. Will be using this from now on.

Answer (score 0):

You can match z and 0-9 with `[Zz0-9]` and you can match a-z and 0-9 with `[a-z0-9]`. If you want both upper and lower case then you would use `[A-Za-z0-9]`.

See [regular expression character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) for more on this.

Further, the `!preg_match()` isn't really necessary. Instead you could use a positive match on what you want, such as `return preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/', $str);` The one you have is actually a negated character class, so it will *disallow* anything within the brackets. I may be misunderstanding your purpose, though.

Comment: Your modification looks like it may only work for single character strings.

Comment: Whoops, that was a typo. Thanks, fixed it.