# jQuery - convert <br> and <br /> and <p /> and such to new line

Tags: jquery, newline

jQuery - How do you convert `<br>` and `<br />` and `<p />` and such to new line?

Does jQuery have a built in `br2nl()` function - this is for converting new lines tags to user-friendly textfield versions.

Comment: Note that PHP’s `nl2br` does not replace new line character sequences but inserts `<br />` in front of it. So e.g. `\r\n` becomes `<br />\r\n` and not just `<br />`.

Comment: this would explain for why the newlines are always so spaced out after a `nl2br` reconvert!

Answer (score 14):

You could create a function like this:

```
jQuery.fn.nl2br = function(){
   return this.each(function(){
     jQuery(this).val().replace(/(<br>)|(<br \/>)|(<p>)|(<\/p>)/g, "\r\n");
   });
};
```

And use it like any of these ways:

```
$(':input').nl2br();
$('textarea').nl2br();
$('#textarea_id').nl2br();
```

Comment: does `/(<br>)|(<p><\/p>)/g` catch also `<br />` ?

Comment: Updated regexp for your plugin: `/(<br\s*\/?>)|(<p><\/p>)/gi`. Don't know how the `<p>` should work, is there content in there?

Comment: @sAc: you asked for my comment: the regex is syntactically correct. The capturing group seems superfluous (i.e. you could've leave out the brackets and it'll still be correct for this case). It will not match `"<p/>"`, but that can easily be added as a fourth alternate. I don't have much experience with jQuery to comment on that part. I hesitate to upvote because I hope there's a much better way to do HTML transformation than regex.

Comment: @polygenelubricants: Thanks for your explanation, that's helpful :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be br2nl as function name? Tried to edit your post but it has been rejected.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to take a chunk of html and replace 
 tags and self-closing  tags with newline characters, doing something like:

```
$('#element-containing-html-to-replace').html().replace(/(<br>)|(<p><\/p>)/g, "\n");
```

should return a string of the container's HTML with those tags replaced with newline characters.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know of, but you can use `"\r\n"`;

EDIT:
Credits to @sAc, but updated to actual replace the value & better regexp:

```
jQuery.fn.nl2br = function(){
    return this.each(function(){
        var that = jQuery(this);
        that.val(that.val().replace(/(<br\s*\/?>)|(<p><\/p>)/gi, "\r\n"));
    });
};
jQuery("textarea").nl2br();
```

Comment: problem with using replace \r\n is that on Windows systems, the \n's don't seem to get processed right

Comment: No problems for me. Try the following in Firebug (or any console) on this page for example: `$("#wmd-input").val("test\r\ntest2");`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code if you want to replace the html-elements itself:

```
$('body').find('br').replaceWith("\n");
$('body').find('p').each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith("\n" + $(this).text() + "\n");
});
```

Comment: is `\r\n` needed or would just `\n` do?