# Function in javascript or jquery like nl2br in php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I need function in javascript or jquery like nl2br in php.
Is there any function in javascript or jquery?if not suggest any equivalent solution.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381331/jquery-convert-br-and-br-and-p-and-such-to-new-line

Comment: @kieran: That's the other way round.

Answer (score 3):

There is the [*php.js* library](http://phpjs.org/pages/home), see [JavaScript nl2br](http://phpjs.org/functions/nl2br:480):

```
function nl2br (str, is_xhtml) {
    // Converts newlines to HTML line breaks  
    // 
    // version: 1109.2015
    // discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/nl2br
    // +   original by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // +   improved by: Philip Peterson
    // +   improved by: Onno Marsman
    // +   improved by: Atli Þór
    // +   bugfixed by: Onno Marsman
    // +      input by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
    // +   bugfixed by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // +   improved by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
    // +   improved by: Maximusya
    // *     example 1: nl2br('Kevin\nvan\nZonneveld');
    // *     returns 1: 'Kevin\nvan\nZonneveld'
    // *     example 2: nl2br("\nOne\nTwo\n\nThree\n", false);
    // *     returns 2: '<br>\nOne<br>\nTwo<br>\n<br>\nThree<br>\n'
    // *     example 3: nl2br("\nOne\nTwo\n\nThree\n", true);
    // *     returns 3: '\nOne\nTwo\n\nThree\n'
    var breakTag = (is_xhtml || typeof is_xhtml === 'undefined') ? '' : '<br>';

    return (str + '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1' + breakTag + '$2');
}
```