# copy text to textarea with all line breaks

Tags: jquery

Hi Friends I want to copy text from `div` to `textarea` including all the line breaks please check fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/SEz5y/

I have tried

**SCRIPT**

```
$('.cancel').click(function(){

var fr = $('.fromCont').html();
$('.contentF').val(fr)

})
```

**HTML**

```
<textarea name="fromCont" rows="5"  class="contentF" id="f" placeholder="Add Text"></textarea>

<div class="fromCont" style="">zxczxczc <br> 1 line <br> 2 line <br> 3 line</div>

<a href="#" class="cancel">submitl</a>
```

Comment: To convert all `br` & `p` (nl2br), try: `fr.replace(/(<br>)|(<br \/>)|(<p>)|(<\/p>)/g, "\r\n");` http://stackoverflow.com/a/3381470/1121982

Answer (score 7):

There are actually no line-breaks in your fiddle. So I am assuming you want to convert the `<br>` to `\n`:

```
$('.contentF').val(fr.replace(/\<br\>/g, "\n"));
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kEgzz/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your `br` tags with the ASCII codes for a carriage return and line feed:

```
$('.contentF').val(fr.replace(/\<br\>/g, '\&#013;&#010;'));
```