# Replace all characters not in range (Java String)

Tags: java, regex, character-class

How do you replace all of the characters in a string that do not fit a criteria.  I'm having trouble specifically with the NOT operator.

Specifically, I'm trying to remove all characters that are not a digit, I've tried this so far:

```
String number = "703-463-9281";
String number2 = number.replaceAll("[0-9]!", ""); // produces: "703-463-9281" (no change)
String number3 = number.replaceAll("[0-9]", "");  // produces: "--" 
String number4 = number.replaceAll("![0-9]", ""); // produces: "703-463-9281" (no change)
String number6 = number.replaceAll("^[0-9]", ""); // produces: "03-463-9281"
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To explain: The ^ at the start of a character class will negate that class But it has to be inside the class for that to work. The same character outside a character class is the anchor for start of string/line instead.

You can try this instead:

```
"[^0-9]"
```

Comment: To explain: The `^` at the start of a *character class* will negate that class But it has to be inside the class for that to work. The same character outside a character class is the anchor for start of string/line instead.

Answer (score 27):

Here's a quick cheat sheet of character class definition and how it interacts with some regex meta characters.

- `[aeiou]` - matches exactly one lowercase vowel
- `[^aeiou]` - matches a character that *ISN'T* a lowercase vowel (*negated* character class)
- `^[aeiou]` - matches a lowercase vowel anchored at the beginning of the line
- `[^^]` - matches a character that isn't a caret/`'^'`
- `^[^^]` - matches a character that isn't a caret at the beginning of line
- `^[^.].` - matches anything but a literal period, followed by "any" character, at the beginning of line
- `[a-z]` - matches exactly one character within the *range* of `'a'` to `'z'` (i.e. all lowercase letters)
- `[az-]` - matches either an `'a'`, a `'z'`, or a `'-'` (literal dash)
- `[.*]*` - matches a contiguous sequence (possibly empty) of dots and asterisks
- `[aeiou]{3}` - matches 3 consecutive lowercase vowels (all not necessarily the same vowel)
- `\[aeiou\]` - matches the string `"[aeiou]"`

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), [Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), [Dot](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html), [Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

#### Related questions

- [Regex: why doesn't `[01-12]` range work as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148240/regex-why-doesnt-01-12-range-work-as-expected)
- [Character class subtraction, converting from Java syntax to RegexBuddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201689/character-class-subtraction-converting-from-java-syntax-to-regexbuddy)
- [How can I exclude some characters from a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548949/how-can-i-exclude-some-characters-from-a-class)