# Replace chars if not match

Tags: regex, illegal-characters

I'm looking for a regular expression that removes illegal characters. But I don't know what the characters will be.

For example:

In a process, I want my string to match `([a-zA-Z0-9/-]*)`. So I would like to replace all characters that **don't match** the regexp above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847294/replace-all-characters-not-in-range-java-string

Answer (score 90, accepted):

That would be:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9/-]+
```

`[^ ]` at the start of a character class negates it - it matches characters not in the class.

See also: [Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Kobi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7586/kobi)'s answer  I've created a [helper method to strips unaccepted characters](http://geekswithblogs.net/mnf/archive/2012/10/28/helper-method-to-replaceremove-characters-that-do-not-match-the.aspx) .

The allowed pattern should be in Regex format, expect them wrapped in square brackets. A function will insert a tilde after  opening squere bracket.
I anticipate that it could work not for all RegEx describing valid characters sets,but it works for relatively simple sets, that we are using.

```csharp
/// <summary>
/// Replaces  not expected characters.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="text"> The text.</param>
/// <param name="allowedPattern"> The allowed pattern in Regex format, expect them wrapped in brackets</param>
/// <param name="replacement"> The replacement.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
/// //        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460290/replace-chars-if-not-match.
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154426/replace-remove-characters-that-do-not-match-the-regular-expression-net
//[^ ] at the start of a character class negates it - it matches characters not in the class.
//Replace/Remove characters that do not match the Regular Expression
static public string ReplaceNotExpectedCharacters( this string text, string allowedPattern,string replacement )
{
  allowedPattern = allowedPattern.StripBrackets( "[", "]" );
  //[^ ] at the start of a character class negates it - it matches characters not in the class.
  var result = Regex.Replace(text, @"[^" + allowedPattern + "]", replacement);
  return result; //returns result free of negated chars
}
```