# Remove non-alphabet (preferably using lambda func or something else short but not for-loop)

Tags: python, string, replace

I have made the following code and basically it outputs how often all characters showed up in a file named 'Test'.

```
from os import strerror
from collections import Counter

try:
    with open ('Test', 'rt') as handle:
        content = handle.read().lower().replace(' ', '').replace('\n', '')
        counts = Counter(content)
    for i in sorted(counts, key=lambda x: counts[x], reverse=True)[:30]:
        print('{} -> {}'.format(i, counts[i]))
    
except IOError as e:
    print('I/O error occurred: ', strerror(e.errno))
```

The output is:

```
e -> 383
o -> 247
s -> 226
t -> 224
n -> 219
a -> 217
r -> 201
i -> 188
d -> 127
h -> 125
l -> 112
c -> 112
m -> 105
u -> 72
f -> 59
p -> 59
g -> 58
y -> 48
b -> 47
. -> 36
w -> 35
, -> 35
v -> 28
k -> 25
0 -> 15
- -> 9
% -> 8
1 -> 7
’ -> 7
x -> 7
```

Afterward I realized I just need the alphabets.
I figured I have to modify line #6:

```
content = handle.read().lower().replace(' ', '').replace('\n', '')
```

I am aware I could just create a for-loop and using following conditional expresstion: `str.isalpha()` to remove non-alphabetic.

I wonder if there's other better ways to do that.

Thank you in advance for your feedback:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it all in one go, using a generator expression or [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
counts = Counter(filter(str.isalpha, handle.read().lower()))
```

Btw, you should also consider using [`Counter.most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) for your output:

```
for k, n in counts.most_common(30):
    print('{} -> {}'.format(k, n))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace this line:

```
content = handle.read().lower().replace(' ', '').replace('\n', '')
```

By this [regex one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460290/replace-chars-if-not-match):

```
import re
content = re.sub("[^a-z/-]+", "", handle.read().lower())
```

In this way you'll remove spaces, newline and non-alphabetic characters in a single pass.