# How to write a regular expression to remove all alphaberical characters from a String

Tags: java, android, regex

How to remove all alphabetical characters from a string usign a regular expression in java/android?

```
val = val.replaceAll("/A/z","");
```

Comment: Spend 5 minutes reading about [character classes](http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex4.html) and you'll know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
replaceAll("[a-z]", "");
```

Also have a look here:

> [Replace all characters not in range (Java String)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847294/replace-all-characters-not-in-range-java-string)

Comment: Worked like a charm! I was a bit close but didn't get there lol cheers

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into [Unicode properites](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop):

`\p{L}` any kind of letter from any language

So your regex would look like this

```
val = val.replaceAll("\\p{L}+","");
```

To remove also combined letters use a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and add `\p{M}`

`\p{M}` a character intended to be combined with another character (e.g. accents, umlauts, enclosing boxes, etc.)

Then you end here:

```
val = val.replaceAll("[\\p{L}\\p{M}]+","");
```

Comment: A good and complete answer totally ignored ... +1

Answer (score 1):

This will remove all alphabetical characters

```
    String text = "gdgddfgdfh123.0114cc";
    String numOnly = text.replaceAll("\\p{Alpha}","");
```