# Regular expression to remove suffixes enclosed in square brackets from comma-delimited list

Tags: regex

I need to format the followin string

```
name[Name], emloyeeno[Employee Number], joindate[Date Of Join:dd MMM yyyy], email[EMail]
```

as

```
name, employeeno, joindate, email
```

I'm trying to use a regular expression to resolve this, I best I could come up with is

```
/\[.*]/g
```

But it is not resolving the problem, I've a sample created [here](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2sbvp).

Can you help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Something like `[aeiou]` matches exactly one of the lowercase vowels. `[^aeiou]` matches one of anything but.

For this problem, you can try `/\[[^\]]*\]/g`.

There are 3 parts:

- `\[` - a literal `[`
- `[^\]]*` - zero-or-more repetition of anything but `]`
- `\]` - a literal `]`

You may also try `/\[.*?\]/` instead if you're lazy.

#### Related questions

- [Difference between `.*?` and `.*` for regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/difference-between-and-for-regex)
- [How can I exclude some characters from a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548949/how-can-i-exclude-some-characters-from-a-class)

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use /\[[^\]]*\]/g instead of /\[.*?\]/ as the first choice? Something like performance or the way in which the regular expression is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

```
/\[(.+?)\]/g
```

This will enforce 1 or more characters inside the brackets.  Also use parens to extract the match.

Answer (score 1):

It is because your regular expression /[.*]/g is a [greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) regular expression.

You regular expression matches all the characters between the first [ and the last ].

You need to change the regular expression as /[.*?]/g

Answer (score 0):

It is because your regular expression is [greedy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html).

You need to modify the regex as [.*?]

You need to modify it as given [here](http://regexr.com?2sbvv)