# Regex matching Unicode variable names

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, unicode, unicode-literals

In Python 2, a Python variable name contains only ASCII letters, numbers and underscores, and it must not start with a number. Thus,

```
 re.search(r'[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*', s)
```

will find a matching Python name in the `str` `s`.

In Python 3, the letters are no longer restricted to ASCII. I am in search for a new regex which will match any and all legal Python 3 variable names.

According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), `\w` in a regex will match any Unicode word literal, including numbers and the underscore. I am however unsure whether this character set contains exactly those characters which might be used in variable names.

Even if the character set `\w` contains exactly the characters from which Python 3 variable names may legally be constructed, how do I use it to create my regex? Using just `\w+` will also match "words" which start with a number, which is no good. I have the following solution in mind,

```
re.search(r'(\w&[^0-9])\w*', s)
```

where `&` is the "and" operator (just like `|` is the "or" operator). The parentheses will thus match any word literal which at the same time is not a number. The problem with this is that the `&` operator does not exist, and so I'm stuck with no solution.

#### Edit

Though the "double negative" trick (as explained in the answer by Patrick Artner below) can also be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548949/how-can-i-exclude-some-characters-from-a-class), note that this only partly answers my question. Using `[^\W0-9]\w*` only works if I am guaranteed that `\w` exactly matches the legal Unicode characters, plus the numbers 0-9. I would like a source of this knowledge, or some other regex which gets the job done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I exclude some characters from a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548949/how-can-i-exclude-some-characters-from-a-class) - is for perl - but non the less about the same...

Comment: See [PEP 3131](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3131/) for the description of what is allowed in non-ASCII identifiers. Here's a list of valid start and continue characters as of Unicode 4.1 from that PEP: https://www.dcl.hpi.uni-potsdam.de/home/loewis/table-3131.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a double negative - `\W` is anything that `\w` is not - just disallow it to allow any `\w`:

```
[^\W0-9]\w*
```

essentially using any not - non-wordcharacter except 0-9 followed by any word character any number of times.

Doku: [regular-expression-syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using

```
^(?![0-9])\w+$
```

Which will not partial match invalid variable names

Alternatively, if you don't need to use regex. `str.isidentifier()` will probably do what you want.