# Pattern compile error

Tags: java, android, regex

I created two patterns to compile `ls -l` outputs in RegexBuddy, but in Android pattern compile gives me an error. In Java 7 it compiled fine.

The raw patterns are

1. `(^[l,d,-][-,r,w,x]{9})[\t,\s]{1,}([[a-z_][a-z0-9_]{0,30}|[0-9]{1,})[\t,\s]{1,}([[a-z_][a-z0-9_]{0,30}|[0-9]{1,})[\t,\s]{1,}([0-9]{0,})[\t,\s]{1,}([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})[\t,\s]{1,}(.{1,})`
2. `(^[l,d,-][-,r,w,x]{9})[\t,\s]{1,}[0-9]{1,}[\t,\s]{1,}([[a-z_][a-z0-9_]{0,30}|[0-9]{1,})[\t,\s]{1,}([[a-z_][a-z0-9_]{0,30}|[0-9]{1,})[\t,\s]{1,}([0-9]{0,})[\t,\s]{1,}(\w{3}\s[0-9]{1,2}[\t,\s]{1,}([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{4}))[\t,\s]{1,}(.{1,})`

The first is for matching

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 doctor users    399 2011-11-11 13:33 shot.s
```

or

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 100 100    399 2011-11-11 13:33 file.txt
```

The second is for matching

for matching

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 doctor users    399 Nov 22  2011 shot.s
```

or

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 100 100    399 Nov 22 13:33 shot.s
```

In code:

1. ```
   private static final Pattern LS_L =
       Pattern.compile("(^[l,d,-][-,r,w,x]{9})[\\t,\\s]{1,}([[a-z_][a-z0-9_]{0,30}|[0-9]{1,})[\\t,\\s]{1,}([[a-z_][a-z0-9_]{0,30}|[0-9]{1,})[\\t,\\s]{1,}([0-9]{0,})[\\t,\\s]{1,}([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}\\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})[\\t,\\s]{1,}(.{1,})");
   ```
2. ```
   private static final Pattern LS_L_1 =
       Pattern.compile("(^[l,d,-][-,r,w,x]{9})[\\t,\\s]{1,}[0-9]{1,}[\\t,\\s]{1,}([[a-z_][a-z0-9_]{0,30}|[0-9]{1,})[\\t,\\s]{1,}([[a-z_][a-z0-9_]{0,30}|[0-9]{1,})[\\t,\\s]{1,}([0-9]{0,})[\\t,\\s]{1,}(\\w{3}\\s[0-9]{1,2}[\\t,\\s]{1,}([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{4}))[\\t,\\s]{1,}(.{1,})");
   ```

The first one throws

```
02-24 21:14:21.854: E/AndroidRuntime(3072): Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Missing closing bracket in character class near index 219:
02-24 21:14:21.854: E/AndroidRuntime(3072): (^[l,d,-][-,r,w,x]{9})[\t,\s]{1,}([[a-z_][a-z0-9_]{0,30}|[0-9]{1,})[\t,\s]{1,}([[a-z_][a-z0-9_]{0,30}|[0-9]{1,})[\t,\s]{1,}([0-9]{0,})[\t,\s]{1,}([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})[\t,\s]{1,}(.{1,})
02-24 21:14:21.854: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):                                                                                                                                                                                                                            ^
02-24 21:14:21.854: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at java.util.regex.Pattern.compileImpl(Native Method)
02-24 21:14:21.854: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:400)
02-24 21:14:21.854: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:383)
02-24 21:14:21.854: E/AndroidRuntime(3072):     at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:374)
```

The second one gives me

```
02-24 21:00:24.166: E/AndroidRuntime(1366): Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Missing closing bracket in character class near index 250:
02-24 21:00:24.166: E/AndroidRuntime(1366): (^[l,d,-][-,r,w,x]{9})[\t,\s]{1,}[0-9]{1,}[\t,\s]{1,}([[a-z_][a-z0-9_]{0,30}|[0-9]{1,})[\t,\s]{1,}([[a-z_][a-z0-9_]{0,30}|[0-9]{1,})[\t,\s]{1,}([0-9]{0,})[\t,\s]{1,}(\w{3}\s[0-9]{1,2}[\t,\s]{1,}([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{4}))[\t,\s]{1,}(.{1,})
```

Comment: Good lord. I think the compiler is just sympathetic to anyone that ever has to look at that.

Comment: what are you trying to match..given the regex i doubt it could be entirely done in regex unless you specify the pattern you are actually trying to match..

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ I said I was matching ls -l output. It can be and must be done with regex. It works perfect in RegexBuddy. Updated the question with examples of output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, the error was removed by escaping the `[` in the `[[a-z_]` character classes - two in each regex.

```
 [\\[a-z_]
```

Some regex implementations do not require `[` to be escaped inside a character class, but java does because *"character classes may appear within other character classes"*. See [Character class subtraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201689/character-class-subtraction-converting-from-java-syntax-to-regexbuddy) and [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Incidentally, you could shorten your regex by replacing all the `[0-9]` with `\\d` and by removing the `\\t` from all the `[\\t,\\s]`, as `\\s` also matches tabs, and by removing all the commas from your character classes e.g. `[-,r,w,x]` should be `[-rwx]`.

And if you weren't worried about the match being case-insensitive you could replace all the `[a-z0-9_]` with `\\w`.

*Edit*

Looking again, there seems to be no reason to have the `[` in the character classes anyway, so `[[a-z_]` should just be `[a-z_]`.

Comment: +1 my first thought was that the useless `,` with multiple occurance could be a problem for a regexx parser that is a bit picky.

Comment: Thanks. The [[ really caused the problem. And I used [0-9] instead of \\d because the documentation encourages to http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: @DoctororDrive. Thanks for the reference: _"if you mean 0-9 use [0-9] rather than \d, which would also include Gurmukhi digits and so forth. "_ I didn't know that other digits would be included. That Android documentation seems pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @Mike said:

1. replace {1,} with +
2. `[a-z_][a-z0-9_]{0,30}` what would you match with that? Certainly not a UNIX filename, for this would rather be something like `[^\0/]+`

Comment: [a-z_][a-z0-9_]{0,30} is an Unix username or group name

Comment: Yes, but why {0,30}? I can imagine having a user `u`, but not one without a name. You could just (\S+) here.

Comment: [a-z_] means one letter without number, then goes zero to 30 letters with numbers allowed [a-z0-9_]{0,30}

Comment: But it just could be a number, or something like `Müller`

Comment: Unix user name can't be a number since it could be treated as UID http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/user-name-restrictions-312024/

Comment: Yes, and in that field we talk about, there goes a user name or a UID. Now, if you do something like ([0-9]+|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+) it is again duplication. [a-zA-Z0-9]+ is just fine (but still doen't match all valid usernames)

Comment: not a duplication. [a-zA-Z0-9]+ will match "123user" which is not a valid name. It should be either a number (UID) or start with a letter.

Comment: But an invalid user name will simply not appear in the output of ls -l. So why check for it?