# Exclude characters from a character class

Tags: regex, set-difference, character-class

Is there a simple way to match all characters in a class except a certain set of them? For example if in a lanaguage where I can use \w to match the set of all unicode word characters, is there a way to just exclude a character like an underscore "_" from that match?

Only idea that came to mind was to use negative lookahead/behind around each character but that seems more complex than necessary when I effectively just want to match a character against a positive match AND negative match. For example if & was an AND operator I could do this...

```
^(\w&[^_])+$
```

Comment: Which flavor of regex are you using? (e.g. Perl, Java, etc.)

Comment: What regex flavor/language? http://stackoverflow.com/q/3201689/139010

Comment: In .NET you could use `[\w-[_]]` to exclude the underscore.

Comment: The regex engine I use most frequently is java based though an old implementation (whatever CF8 uses under the hood). However I also have this need in javascript and python.

Comment: You mean ColdFusion?  That's based on JavaScript, not Java.  And its `\w` only recognizes the ASCII word characters (`[A-Za-z0-9_]`), not the full Unicode set.  Same goes for Python's built-in `re` flavor.

Comment: Perl solutions are found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69633772/589924).

Answer (score 32):

It really depends on your regex flavor.

### .NET

... provides only one simple character class set operation: [subtraction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#CharacterClassSubtraction). This is enough for your example, so you can simply use

```
[\w-[_]]
```

If a `-` is followed by a nested character class, it's subtracted. Simple as that...

### Java

... provides a much richer set of [character class set operations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). In particular you can get the intersection of two sets like `[[abc]&&[cde]]` (which would give `c` in this case). Intersection and negation together give you subtraction:

```
[\w&&[^_]]
```

### Perl

... supports set operations on [extended character classes](https://perldoc.pl/perlrecharclass#Extended-Bracketed-Character-Classes) as an experimental feature (available since Perl 5.18). In particular, you can directly subtract arbitrary character classes:

```
(?[ \w - [_] ])
```

### All other flavors

... (that support lookaheads) allow you to mimic the subtraction by using a negative lookahead:

```
(?!_)\w
```

This first checks that the next character is not a `_` and then matches any `\w` (which can't be `_` due to the negative lookahead).

Note that each of these approaches is completely general in that you can subtract two arbitrarily complex character classes.

Answer (score 14):

You can use a negation of the `\w` class (--> `\W`) and exclude it:

```
^([^\W_]+)$
```

Comment: Creative, but I don't think the OP expected this kind of answer, he wants to exclude a character in a general case. Nice idea though

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I should have thought of this. HamZa is right that I was looking for a more general case, but woah... \p... thank you for pointing that out as I have never used it.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte not *all* cases. This cannot be used to exclude a character from a range ;).

Comment: Not all RE engines support that.

Comment: @DonalFellows what do you mean by "that"? Negated character classes?

Comment: This works great, but only with a *single* class *except some characters* (e.g. `\w` without `_`), *not* with *multiple* classes *except some characters* (e.g. `\w` and `\p{P}` without `_`).

Comment: @caw: your example is out of the scope of the question, and except for regex flavors that allows operations inside character classes (intersections, substractions), I doubt there's a miraculous solution (without to use your little fingers to build it with ranges) . However, for your particular example, you can do that with pcre in unicode mode: `[[:alnum:]\pP]` or `[\p{Xan}\pP]` . In other words, you have to find the best solution for each case with the predefined classes available.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte This was not criticism of your answer. On the contrary, I upvoted it and agree that it’s the perfect answer for this specific question. My comment was just intended as advice for people with adjacent problems.

Comment: @caw: sorry if my answer looks rude, I am not ~totally~fluent~ in english. Your comments are welcome and the critics too. Thanks for "the perfect answer", other answers are useful too.

Answer (score 11):

A negative lookahead is the correct way to go insofar as I understand your question:

```
^((?!_)\w)+$
```

Answer (score 8):

This can be done in **python** with the [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex). Something like:

```
import regex as re
pattern = re.compile(r'[\W_--[ ]]+')
cleanString = pattern.sub('', rawString)
```

You'd typically install the regex module with [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/):

```
pip install regex
```

**EDIT**:

The regex module has two behaviours, version 0 and version 1. Set substraction (as above) is a version 1 behaviour. The pypi docs claim version 1 is the default behaviour, but you may find this is not the case. You can check with

```
import regex
if regex.DEFAULT_VERSION == regex.VERSION1:
  print("version 1")
```

To set it to version 1:

```
regex.DEFAULT_VERSION = regex.VERSION1
```

or to use version one in a single expression:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(?V1)[\W_--[ ]]+')
```

Comment: Lifesaver on the VERSION1 bit. I would have gone crazy otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

Try using subtraction:

```
[\w&&[^_]]+
```

Note: This will work in Java, but might not in some other Regex engine.