# How to match against differences of character groups in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, character, string-matching

The regular expression `/^[a-z]*$/` is a quick way to match against all characters in the range.

But how can I remove a group of characters from that range?

For instance, what regular expression matches against `a-z` with `e,o,u` excluded?

Of course, I can manually put the multiple ranges but I wonder whether there is any better way?

---

EDIT. A [similar but more broad question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327765/exclude-characters-from-a-character-class) did not refer to JavaScript. However, JavaScript has a special treatment of regular expressions, see [here](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode#regex) for instance. Many expressions from other languages do not work in JavaScript, so I feel a separate more specific JS questions deserves some merit.

Comment: `/^(?:(?![oeu])[a-z])*$/` I believe, based on the answers there... A negative lookahead and the character class, grouped together with a non-capturing group, repeated zero or more times.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks! It would be hard to dig that among all those answers, many of which do not work in JS.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the answer here so that this question doesn't show as unanswered:

```
/^(?:(?![oeu])[a-z])*$/
```

Credit goes to T.J. Crowder