# How to replace all non-ASCII characters, except quotes?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
const x = "Amanda’s normally placid temperament ��新道 reasserted itself."

const y = `x.replace(/[\u{0080}-\u{FFFF}]/gu, '');` 

console.log(y); // Amandas normally placid temperament  reasserted itself.
```

This removes the non-ASCII characters(desired), along with the apostrophe too (not desired).

How can I modify the regex such that it does not remove the following:

```
U+0022 - Apostrophe
U+2019 - Right single quotation mark
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17328119/3832970) in the linked thread, under *All other flavors*

Comment: x.replace(/(?!')[\u{0080}-\u{FFFF} ']/gu, '') ... This replaces all the spaces too (undesired)

Comment: Yes, because you added a space to the character class. If you do not need that behavior, remove it

Comment: x.replace(/(?!')[\u{0080}-\u{FFFF}]/gu, '') ... doesn't do much. Doesn't remove the apostrophe

Comment: Look, you have `[\u{0080}-\u{FFFF}]`. To add the exceptions you have, just add a lookahead, `(?![\u{2019}])[\u{0080}-\u{FFFF}]` (and you may add more chars to the character class in the lookahead). The `U+0022 - Apostrophe` does not have to be added, as it is out of the range. If it does not do what you need, your question should be modified to clarify what you are doing and need to achieve

Comment: Got it. Thanks. It is best to delete this question then, right ? To avoid confusion ?

Comment: You do not have to.