# regex to get words that contain some characters and does not contain some others

Tags: regex

what I want is a regex that gets words that contains for example character `a` and does not contain characters `b` and `c`

it seemed to me that the following does half of the job.

```
^[^bc]+$
```

but I want words. and containing `a` is not considered here.

Comment: If you mean words in longer texts, `\b[ad-z]+\b`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that does correctly gives the words without `b` and `c`. but `b` and `c` were just examples, I need words that contain some characters and don't contain some other characters

Comment: sorry if I came out as condescending. what I need is a general solution. for example with `^[^bc]+$` you can replace `b` and `c` with any character you want. but it is not possible with your solution.

Comment: You need one of the solutions in [Exclude characters from a character class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327765/exclude-characters-from-a-character-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative look ahead `(?!...)` to make sure that the word that we will capture has no `b` nor `c`. Then, match if the word has any `a`.

```
\b(?!\w*[bc]\w*)\w*a\w*\b
```

[image]

Where:

- `\b` - Match the word boundary marking the start of the word
- `(?!\w*[bc]\w*)` - Negative look ahead. Match the next characters (which is the word) only if it doesn't contain "b" nor "c".
- `\w*a\w*` - Match the word if it contains any "a"
- `\b` - Match the word boundary marking the end of the word