# .NET character class subtraction support in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have this regex (`"^[-A-Z0-9-[O]]{1,8}$"`) comming from a client requirement (normally should not be changed).
But it doesn't work in python (it works in C).

```
from re import search

var = "MY01C0DE"
regex = "^[-A-Z0-9-[O]]{1,8}$"

print(search(regex, var))
```

this prints None.

But if I change the regex to `"^[-A-NP-Z0-9]{1,8}$"`, this works.

```
from re import search

var = "MY01C0DE"
regex = "^[-A-NP-Z0-9]{1,8}$"

print(search(regex, var))
```

So basically the `-[O]` part doesn't work in python if I understand correctly. But I have checked and this regex works in C.
Is there any way to make this way of excluding characters (`-[O]`) work in python also?

Comment: See https://www.rexegg.com/regex-class-operations.html#subtraction and for the Python regex module https://www.rexegg.com/regex-class-operations.html#subtraction_python

Comment: `[-A-Z0-9-[O]]` does not work in C, it works in C#, as the .NET regex flavor supports this character class subtraction syntax.

Comment: You can use PyPi `regex` module, then it will work.

Comment: It is here with the PyPi regex module https://stackoverflow.com/a/39024781/5424988

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PyPi `regex` module that supports .NET-like [character class subtraction](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-class-operations.html#subtraction) and use

```py
from regex import search, V1

var = "MY01C0DE"
regex = "^[-A-Z0-9-[O]]{1,8}$"
print(search(regex, var, V1))
# => <regex.Match object; span=(0, 8), match='MY01C0DE'>
```

See the [Python demo](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1ehKDU9tUIhM7cgv6hEoTg1sSg5Q0chzJCLqyyxSMFWQck30sDQ2cDFVYkLohIoFBet66gbZaBrqRvtHxtbbahjUauixFVQlJlXogExQQOsVkcBaAbIME3N//8B).

Check the ["*Nested sets and set operations*" section](https://pypi.org/project/regex/#nested-sets-and-set-operations):

> For example, the pattern `[[a-z]--[aeiou]]` is treated in the version 0 behaviour (simple sets, compatible with the re module) as:
>
> - Set containing “[” and the letters “a” to “z”
> - Literal “–”
> - Set containing letters “a”, “e”, “i”, “o”, “u”
> - Literal “]”
>
> but in the version 1 behaviour (nested sets, enhanced behaviour) as:
>
> - Set which is:
>
>   - Set containing the letters “a” to “z”
> - but excluding:
>
>   - Set containing the letters “a”, “e”, “i”, “o”, “u”
>
> Version 0 behaviour: only simple sets are supported.
> Version 1 behaviour: nested sets and set operations are supported.