# Java regex "[.]" vs "."

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to use some regex in Java and I came across this when debugging my code.

What's the difference between `[.]` and `.`?

I was surprised that `.at` would match "cat" but `[.]at` wouldn't.

Comment: Did you go through any regex tutorial? `.` is a meta-character which matches anything except a newline. Inside a character class, it isn't a meta-character.

Comment: Yes, I have been looking at the oracle tutorials. `[abc]` is a character class that matches a, b, or c. So why doesn't `[.]` act the same as `.`?

Comment: ahh, I didn't understand that inside it's own character class it's no longer a meta-character. Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`[.]` matches a dot (`.`) literally, while `.` matches any character except newline (`\n`) (unless you use [`DOTALL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) mode).

You can also use `\.` (`"\\."` if you use java string literal) to literally match dot.

Comment: Any character, but the new-line one (by default at least ;)

Answer (score 4):

The `[` and `]` are *metacharacters* that let you define a [*character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Anything enclosed in square brackets is interpreted literally. You can include multiple characters as well:

```
[.=*&^$] // Matches any single character from the list '.','=','*','&','^','$'
```

There are two specific things you need to know about the `[...]` syntax:

- The `^` symbol at the beginning of the group has a special meaning: it inverts what's matched by the group. For example, `[^.]` matches any character except a dot `.`
- Dash `-` in between two characters means any code point between the two. For example, `[A-Z]` matches any single uppercase letter. You can use dash multiple times - for example, `[A-Za-z0-9]` means "any single upper- or lower-case letter or a digit".

The two constructs above (`^` and `-`) are common to nearly all regex engines; some engines  (such as Java's) define [additional syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3201689/335858) specific only to these engines.

Comment: You can find [character class union/intersection/substraction](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3201747/1225328) too actually ;)

Comment: @sp00m That's true - thanks, I edited the answer to mention it.

Answer (score 1):

[regular-expression constructs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

> . =>  *Any character (may or may not match line terminators)*

---

and to match the dot  .  use the following

```
[.] => it will matches a dot
\\. => it will matches a dot
```

**NOTE:** The character classes in Java regular expression is defined using the square brackets "[ ]", this subexpression matches a single character from the specified or, set of possible characters.

> **Example :** In string address replaces every "." with "[.]"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String address = "1.1.1.1";
    System.out.println(address.replaceAll("[.]","[.]"));
}
```

if anything is missed please add :)