# Regular expression for persian(arabic) letters without any numbers

Tags: java, regex, arabic, persian

In Java i'm looking for a regular expression that accepts any Persian( or Arabic ) letters except any Persian ( or Arabic) numbers.
In order to have only letters i found a very good regular expression:

`[\u0600-\u065F\u066A-\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FF]`

although it is true and works for me, But we know that we can use the `\\p{L}+` as a regular expression which accepts all letters from all languages in the world, and in my case ( Arabic - Persian ) i can modified it and use `[\\p{InArabic}]+$.`

But by using `[\\p{InArabic}]+$` not only all Arabic(Persian) letters are going to be accepted but also Arabic numbers are acceptable too, like ۱ ۲.

So my question is how can i modify `[\\p{InArabic}]+$` to just accept letters not numbers, or in other word how can i restrict `[\\p{InArabic}]+$` to not accept any numbers?

Please Notice that the Persian(Arabic) numbers are like these: ۱ ۲ ۳ ۴ ۵ ۶ ۷ ۸ ۹ ۰

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
"[\\p{InArabic}&&\\PN]"
```

`\p{InArabic}` matches any character in Unicode Block Arabic (from U+0600 to U+06FF)

`\PN` matches any character **not** belonging to any of the Number category (note the capital `P`).

Intersecting the 2 sets give the desired result: both digit ranges (U+0660 to U+0669) and (U+06F0 to U+06F9) are excluded.

### Testing code

```
for (int i = 0x600; i <= 0x6ff; i++) {
    String c = "" + (char) i;
    System.out.println(Integer.toString(i, 16) + " " + c.matches("[\\p{InArabic}&&\\PN]"));
}
```

Comment: are you sure it should be like this? `[\\p{InArabic}&&\\PN] ` because my IDE shows me a red line behind of \\PN :(
It says : character category expected.

Comment: @ElyasHadizadeh: I have tested the regex on my machine (Java 7 and Java 8) before posting. Note that I'm specifying the regex inside string literal. Remove one ``\`` if you need the raw form.

Comment: yes you are true and it works as a charm, but it's very strange that my IDE draws a red line behind of \\PN. ( I am using IntelliJ IDEA 13.0.4, with Java 7 and Java 8, in both cases it shows red line behind of \\PN, but when i compile and run the application it works correctly.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, What is your IDE? do you know why do i get such a bug?

Comment: @ElyasHadizadeh: I use Eclipse, but Eclipse doesn't do any validity detection on regex. The most it does is check syntax of string literal.

Comment: aha ! that's the reason, because the IntelliJ do validity detection on regex, and it seems that `"[\\p{InArabic}&&\\PN]"` is very strange for it. but you know it just shows a red line under it. in the compiling and running it doesn't have any problem. any way thank you buddy

Answer (score 7):

You can use [character class subtraction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3201689/7586), which is a rather obscure feature:

```
[\p{InArabic}&&[^۰-۹]]
```

Working example: http://ideone.com/jChGem

Comment: Hey buddy, thank you, unfortunately your regular expression is just acceptable in .Net technologies and i am looking for a Java Programming Language.

Comment: unfortunately your edited answer does not work, you know? i think Java does not support [^۰-۹], i don't know :-??

Comment: @ElyasHadizadeh - Weird... Seems to be working for me: http://ideone.com/jChGem . Can you please post your code in the question?

Comment: You need to also exclude the range `[٠-٩]`, current regex only excludes the code points from U+06F0 to U+06F9

Comment: @nhahtdh - Isn't that exactly the range I have? What am I missing?

Comment: The range I suggested `[٠-٩]` is the range U+0660 to U+0669. It is missing in your answer.

Comment: @nhahtdh - Oh, got it. lookalikes.