# How to prevent accented characters in an email field in Java using regex?

Tags: java, regex, validation

I have an email field in a form which is currently validated using GenericValidator.isEmail method. But now I need to apply another validation where I need to prevent accented characters being sent to the email address. So I was thinking of using a Regex Pattern Matching approach and I found one in stackoverflow itself

```
if (Pattern.matches(".*[éèàù].*", input)) {
  // your code
}
```

Problem is I saw only é è à ù characters in the pattern but there are several other accented characters like õ ü ì etc. So is there a way we can match pattern for all types of accented characters?
I needed to match for NL (Dutch), FR(French) and DE(German) language accented characters. I need to check if my email address has any accented character and if it does need to stop execution there and throw an error

Comment: Maybe subtract the `A-Za-z` from `\p{L}`? `Pattern.matches("(?s).*[\\p{L}&&[^A-Za-z]].*", input)`?

Comment: I am new to regex pattern matching. could you kindly tell me the meaning of "?s" and "\\p{L}". Just unable to evaluate what this pattern is evaluating to from the left

Comment: Does it work as intended for you? It matches `ł`, `ф`, `Й`, etc., any letters but the ASCII letters.

Comment: are you sure only accent characters are problem for you? E.g. German alphabet does not have accented letters, per se, they are ü, ö, ä which is not exactly accented. Can we assume you want only English characters from all alphabets out there?

Comment: Yes I tried with èàùüõìÉǞ and it works infact all of the accented characters I tried but did not get what you meant by ASCII letters? U mean the normal a-z and A-Z for which there are ASCII Codes right? only for these it wont work?

Comment: Yes, ASCII letters means the "English" letters from the English alphabet.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew well thanks it works indeed !! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you want to match any letter but an ASCII letter.

I suggest [substracting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201689/character-class-subtraction-converting-from-java-syntax-to-regexbuddy) ASCII letters from the `\p{L}` pattern that matches any Unicode letter:

```java
Pattern.matches("(?s).*[\\p{L}&&[^A-Za-z]].*", input)
```

Here,

- `(?s)` - `Pattern.DOTALL` embedded flag option that makes `.` match across lines
- `.*` - any zero or more chars, as many as possible
- `[\\p{L}&&[^A-Za-z]]` - any Unicode letter except ASCII letters
- `.*` - any zero or more chars, as many as possible.

Note it is better to use `find()` since it also returns partial matches, and there is no need using `(?s).*` and `.*` in the above pattern, making it much more efficient with longer strings:

```java
Pattern.compile("[\\p{L}&&[^A-Za-z]]").matcher(input).find()
```

See [this Java demo](https://ideone.com/nFTt9x).