# Regular expression to remove ASCII control characters in Java

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I've been reading that the below pattern used as part of `String#replaceAll()` in Java

```
"[\\p{Cntrl}&&[^\r\n\t]]"
```

removes various non-printable ASCII characters from it.

How does one interpret the above incantation:

- which characters are included as part of those control chars to be removed?
- what does the `&&` stand for?
- does `^` mean it only looks at the beginning of the line?

Can someone please provide a comprehensive **non-technical** explanation of the above expression?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Go to https://regex101.com/ and the site will explain it to you. I am not familiar with what `\p{Cntrl}` does, also I am not aware of any special meaning of `&&` or that nested character classes even exist.

Comment: None of this appears to be standard regex.  You would be better off using `[\x00-\x1F]` since the set of control characters are the first 32 (hexadecimal 20) non_printable ASCII characters.  That range includes \r (ctl-M), \n (ctl-J), and \t (ctl-I).

Comment: Possible duplicates: *[Regex java. Why using intersection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930181/regex-java-why-using-intersection)*, *[What is the point behind character class intersections in Java's Regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106387)*, *[Character class subtraction, converting from Java syntax to RegexBuddy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3201689)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"... which characters are included as part of those control chars to be removed? ..."*

You can find this information in the *Pattern* class *JavaDoc*.

*[Pattern – POSIX character classes (US-ASCII only) – (Java SE 20 & JDK 20)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum)*.

> *\p{Cntrl}    A control character: [\x00-\x1F\x7F]*

Which is, from values *0 through 1f*, and value *7f*.

> *"... what does the `&&` stand for? ..."*

The `&&` is part of the syntax for a *character class intersection*.

For example, the following will match any character, *a* through *z*, except for *x* and *y*.

```
[a-z&&[^xy]]
```

> *"... does `^` mean it only looks at the beginning of the line? ..."*

Not when within a *character class*, `[ ]`.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things going on here that are only available in some flavors of regex.  You may encounter differences in implementation or availability in different languages.

Where supported, you can define a character class with multiple classes within it.  For example, `[[a-z][0-9]]` is a valid equivalent to `[a-z0-9]`.

Where the `&&` operator is supported, it can be used to create a character class that is the intersection of two character classes.  For example, `[[a-z]&&[^d-w]]` would be equivalent to `[abcxyz]`.

There are a bunch of predefined character classes that can be referenced with `\p{category_name}`.  In Java, the category `\p{Cntrl}` represents `[\x00-\x1F\x7F]`.  You can find examples within the Java Docs for `java.util.regex.Pattern`.
(See : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

So, your regex matches every character in the range `[\x00-\x1F\x7F]` except for characters `[\r\n\t]`.

Comment: That "intersection" is gold! Thanks for this explanation. Can't say how much I love this site, everyday a new thing :)

Comment: "*[...] not in JavaScript or Perl.*": I don't know about Perl, but the ECMAScript engine [does support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/unicodeSets) Unicode set operations. The regex needs to be rewritten as [`[[\p{Control}]&&[^\r\n\t]]`](https://regex101.com/r/Jg4dQS/1), though.

Comment: @InSync While `\p{Control}` may be interpreted by ECMAScript as expected, nesting and intersecting classes will fail.  Test your regex and see.

Comment: [Fail how](https://regex101.com/r/Jg4dQS/2)?

Comment: @InSync Fail to work as expected.  The `&&` will, for example, be interpreted as a literal.

Comment: Does your browser support the new-ish `v` flag? If it does, you should see something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPlMD.png).

Comment: @InSync I wasn't aware of the `v` flag.  Do you know if that's supported in `nodejs`?

Comment: [Node.js 20+](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V20.md#v8-113), yes.

Comment: Why is JavaScript being discussed when the question is about Java?

Answer (score 1):

The pattern matches a character which is in the set of control characters `\\p{Cntrl}` intersected (by `&&`) with the set of characters that are not line break , carriage return or tab `[^\r\n\t]`. Example:

```
"a\u0001b\u0002c\rd\te\nf".replaceAll("[\\p{Cntrl}&&[^\r\n\t]]","-");
=> control codes 0001 and 0002 are removed: "a-b-c\rd\te\nf"
```

To help explain, consider swapping `\\p{Cntrl}` for `[a-z]` and `[^\r\n\t]` with `[^aeiou]`, and then you will have a pattern that can be used to filter out consonants:

```
"123abcdef".replaceAll("[[a-z]&&[^aeiou]]","-");
=> "123a---e-"
```

Comment: Interesting. afaicr ops on character classes isn't even documented..?

Comment: Looks like [JDK20 doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) does mention them briefly, not sure about older JDK

Comment: Does `intercept` mean `except` in English?  Or does it mean something else, i.e. AND?

Comment: @SimeonLeyzerzon  I think you might be thinking of *intersect*, which is what sets do (think Venn diagram) What we have here though is *exclusion* (AND NOT)

Comment: @SimeonLeyzerzon The action is like AND and applies when defining the character class, but because the second part of the expression starts `[^` it defines the second set as not in this group of characters